# Objective c properties to unmanaged c++

Tags: c++, objective-c, properties

how could it be translated to unmanaged c++ from objective c

1

```
property ( nonatomic, assign, getter = isCanceled ) BOOL canceled;
```

by the  way  - isCanceled = false; so why not to wright

```
property ( nonatomic, assign) BOOL canceled;
```

as in another part of code with other operators:

2

```
property ( nonatomic, retain ) Im* img;
```

and is this construction is simply constant in c++?

3

property ( nonatomic, readonly ) Parameter* firstPar;
so is this in c++  something like variable

```
const Parameter* firstPar;
```

?

and how to translate first and second properties correctly???

Comment: I think I must write two separate functions - one is getter and other is setter but I dont know the difference between 1 and 2 and I am not sure about 3. Buy the way it will be ugly anyway - cause I will implement two new names(for getter and setter) where at objective c was one (for property)

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, in C++ it might look like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    bool m_cancelled;

public:
    bool isCancelled()
    {
        return m_cancelled;
    }

    void setCancelled(bool b)
    {
        m_cancelled = b;
    }
};
```

Alternatively, I have found that most C++ classes that implement accessor methods usually use `getXyz` and `setXyz()` naming convention, which is quite different from the typical Objective-C convention of just `xyz` and `setXyz:`, so it may make more sense to name the `isCancelled()` method `getCancelled()`.

For pointer types, it can get tricky. There is no sole memory ownership model like there is with Cocoa, so it's hard to translate exactly what a `retain` property should do, but in C++ there are these nifty little things called [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer). Learn about how smart pointers, and about which type of smart pointer is useful for your other data/class types. For example, you might find [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) useful.

A read-only property in C++ would probably look something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    int m_someProp;

public:
    int getSomeProp()
    {
        return m_someProp;
    }

    MyClass(int initialValue) : m_someProp(initialValue)
    {
        // m_someProp can still be altered anywhere within any method within
        // MyClass, but users of MyClass will only have access to the value
        // via getSomeProp()
    }
}
```